# Is a Transit Visa necessary for a brief layover at London Heathrow airport

Tags: schengen, uk, indian-citizens

I will be transiting through London Heathrow airport on 2 occasions:
 1) On 22 Sept 2016 BA flight from Bangalore to London, arrival at 13.05 hrs: departure at 14-55 hrs for Paris by BA flight.
 2) On 11 Oct 2016 BA flight from Berlin to London, arrival at 12-10 hrs: departure at 14-25 hrs for Bangalore by BA flight.
 I have confirmed British Airways tickets for entire journey. I have a valid Schengen visa. I book checked-in baggage at Bangalore and Berlin.
 DO I NEED ANY TRANSIT VISA for Short Layover?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you hold an Indian passport and a Schengen short-stay visa, yes, you Need an airside transit visa for the UK.

Only if you have a Schengen long-stay visa or residence permit can you transit the UK without a visa